# Nodejs MySQL multiple query in a loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sockets

i'm actually having a problem by doing alot of query in a loop
It's seem to not work aswell, 100% of time is only query the latest data in the array.

```
CurrentSocket.biznessStatus.ListOfItemsToAdd = ["1", "4"];    
if(Object.keys(CurrentSocket.biznessStatus.ListOfItemsToAdd).length >= 1){
        for(var id in CurrentSocket.biznessStatus.ListOfItemsToAdd){
            var readedIt = CurrentSocket.biznessStatus.ListOfItemsToAdd[id];

            pool.getConnection(function(id, err, connection){
                if(err) throw err;

                console.log("doAction of ListOfItemsToAdd for itemID -> "+readedIt);

                connection.query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS it FROM users_biznesspanel WHERE user_id = ? AND ui_id = ?", [CurrentSocket.user_id, readedIt], function(err, result){
                    if(err) console.log(err);
                    if(result[0]["it"] != 0){
                        connection.query("UPDATE users_biznesspanel SET nb = nb + 1 WHERE user_id = ? AND ui_id = ?", [CurrentSocket.user_id, readedIt], function(err, result){
                            connection.release();
                            if(err) console.log(err);
                            console.log("Added item: "+readedIt);
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        connection.query("SELECT type FROM items WHERE iid = ?", [readedIt], function(err, result){
                            if(err) console.log(err);
                            var catInfo = getItemType(result[0]["type"]);

                            var insertItem = "INSERT INTO users_biznesspanel(user_id, ui_id, icat, iscat) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)";
                            connection.query(insertItem, [CurrentSocket.user_id, readedIt, catInfo.cat, catInfo.scat], function(err, result){
                                connection.release();
                                if(err) console.log(err);
                                console.log("Inserted item: "+readedIt);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            }.bind(pool, id));
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need to refactor your code to make better use of control flow. The site [callbackhell.com](http://callbackhell.com/) has some guides on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to query SQL in one complex sql, you could use the "case when" grammar,for example:

```
case sex
when '1' then '男'
when '2' then '女’
else '其他' end
```

And I always use 'sequelize' module in NodeJS to help me query sql. It would be safer and you could focus on your logistic.